# Saving pandas table to the particular directory

Tags: python, pandas

So I have a code (im connecting raspberry pi with arduino, sending data from sensors and now I try to save it to html:

```
df.to_html("Table.html")
```

I wanted to ask if it is possible to overwrite the apaches server index.html so the data will be visible outside. Would simply overwriting the index.html do the trick? If yes, I'd grateful for the tip how to save to its directory. I tried giving the specific path to df.to_html("home/pi/table.html") but I ended up wit the file called home/pi/table.html :o)
Thank you in advance !

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that the path should be "/home/pi/Table.html"